# Color Picker Farbtastic sync on 2 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic

I would like to have a few INPUT and users can change color for each. However, each input is synced with some other classes (like body background color, or menu background color).

I want to be able to change color with Farbtastic Color Picker and it affects BOTH the INPUT and the CLASS / ID that synced with the INPUT. How to do that? The example below will make color in "colorwell" changed only but how to sync other element to #color1, #color2... separately? Thanks

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demo').hide();
    var f = $.farbtastic('#picker');
    //var p = $('#picker').css('opacity', 0.25);
    //var selected;
    $('.colorwell')
      .each(function () { f.linkTo(this);  })
      .focus(function() {
        //if (selected) {
        //  $(selected).css('opacity', 0.75).removeClass('colorwell-selected');
        //}
        f.linkTo(this);
        //p.css('opacity', 1);
        //$(selected = this).css('opacity', 1).addClass('colorwell-selected');
      });
  });
 </script>


<form action="" style="width: 500px;">
  <div id="picker" style="float: right;"></div>
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color1">Color 1:</label><input type="text" id="color1" name="color1" class="colorwell" value="#123456" /></div>
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color2">Color 2:</label><input type="text" id="color2" name="color2" class="colorwell" value="#123456" /></div>
  <div class="form-item"><label for="color3">Color 3:</label><input type="text" id="color3" name="color3" class="colorwell" value="#123456" /></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to modify the farbtastic.js file slightly... basically I added this line:

```
$('.' + this.id).css('background-color',fb.color);
```

below line 234 in the original script. It takes the ID from the currently selected input box and changes the background-color of the same class as the ID. So changing `#color1` with farbtastic will also update the `.color1` class. You may need to modify the farbtastic.js yourself if you want change something other than the background color.

Get the modified [farbtastic.js](http://www.myotherdrive.com/dyn/file/968.580911.07112009.10294.6a64fi/farbtastic.js) here and see a [demo here](http://www.myotherdrive.com/dyn/file/468.241511.07112009.10430.6a64fi/demo1.html).